# Can't get flexdashboard modal Shiny reactivity to deal with NULL state

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

First off, here's a minimal reproducible example:

Suppose I have the following `flexdashboard` app **example.Rmd**:

````
---
title: "Test App"
output:
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme: ["lumen"]
    orientation: ["columns"]
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
source('modules.R')
```

Test
==================

Inputs {.sidebar data-width=250}
------------------

```{r}

## Modules:
globalInputs <- callModule(setup, "inputs")  # Note: you only need to call this one time!
callModule(chart, "modalChart", globalInputs)
## UI:
sidebar("inputs")

```

Column
-------------------------------------

### ModalTest

```{r}
chartUI2("modalChart")
```
````

Here's my **modules.R** file:

```
sidebar <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    helpText("Press the button below to pull up a modal:"),
    actionButton(ns("settings"), "Settings", icon = icon("cogs"), width = '100%')
  )
}

# setup function
setup <- function(input, output, session) {
  return(input)  ## Note, input in this case is a reactive list of values that you can index against with $ or [[""]]
}

# UI module for the popup Settings modal
modalUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  withTags({  # UI elements for the modal go in here
    ## Note: you can use the fluidPage() and fluidRow() functions to define a column-based UI for the chart inputs below:
    fluidPage(
      fluidRow(sliderInput(ns("bins"), "Number of bins:",
                           min = 1,  max = 50, value = 30),
               textInput(ns("plotTitle"), label = "Plot Title", value = "This is a test")
      ))
  })
}


## UI module for the 2 buttons in the modal:
modalFooterUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    modalButton("Cancel", icon("remove")),
    actionButton(ns("modalApply"), "Apply", icon = icon("check"))
  )
}

## chart module ----------------------------------------------------------------
chartUI2 <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  plotOutput(ns("distPlot"))
}

chart <- function(input, output, session, setup) {

  observeEvent(setup$settings, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      modalUI("inputs"),  # Call UI function defined in './modules/modal.R'; note the namespace 'inputs' is the same globally for the app
      title = "Settings",
      footer = modalFooterUI("inputs"),
      size = "l",
      easyClose = TRUE,
      fade = TRUE)
    )
  })

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    if (setup$settings == 0)
      return(
        hist(faithful[, 2],
             breaks = 5,  # if the button hasn't been pressed, default
             main = 'This is the default title',
             col = 'darkgray',
             border = 'white')
      )
    isolate({
      x <- faithful[, 2]
      bins <- setup$bins
      hist(x,
           breaks = bins,
           main = setup$plotTitle,
           col = 'darkgray',
           border = 'white')
    })

  })
}
```

**Here's what I want to accomplish:**

1. When the page loads render `distPlot` with default parameters. This should always happen.
2. When I click the 'Settings' `actionButton`, it pops up the modal overlay (but keeps the plot in the background in its original state)
3. Allow the user to change the parameters in the pop-up modal, but do not re-render the plot until the user hits the 'Apply' button.

I think I have #1 figured out, but when I click the 'Settings' button I get an error `Invalid breakpoints produced by 'breaks(x)': NULL`. Then, I change the inputs and it does nothing (except until I hit the Settings `actionButton` again (which in turn renders the plot with the given inputs).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a timing issue. When you press the settings button, `setup$settings` becomes 1 so the `renderPlot` tries to replot. If this happens before the slider is set up, `setup$bins` is `NULL` and you get an error.

You could add a condition in the first `if` of your `renderPlot` to plot with `setup$bins` only when the user presses the Apply button in the modal:

```
output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    if (setup$settings == 0 | !isTruthy(setup$modalApply)) {
        hist(faithful[, 2],
             breaks = 5,  # if the button hasn't been pressed, default
             main = 'This is the default title',
             col = 'darkgray',
             border = 'white')
      } else {
    isolate({
      x <- faithful[, 2]
      bins <- setup$bins
      hist(x,
           breaks = bins,
           main = setup$plotTitle,
           col = 'darkgray',
           border = 'white')
    })
```

`!isTruthy` will be `TRUE` if `setup$modalApply` is `NULL` (modal hasn't been created) or if it is `0` (user hasn't pressed the button yet).
Once the user presses the Apply button, the plot is updated.

**Edit:**

To make it easier, you can use a `reactiveValues` to hold all your plot parameters, including the default ones. It can be updated when the user clicks the apply button, which in turn updates the plot:

```
 plot_params = reactiveValues(bins=5,title='This is the default title')


  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        hist(faithful[, 2],
             breaks = plot_params$bins,
             main = plot_params$title,
             col = 'darkgray',
             border = 'white')
  })

  observeEvent(setup$modalApply,{
    plot_params$bins = setup$bins
    plot_params$title = setup$plotTitle
  })
```

Comment: Thanks man!! That seems to work, but there's one problem: After I click 'Apply', the plot renders (As it should), but when I click the 'Settings' button again, it resets it back to the original state. Is there a way to keep the last values for the slider and title? Also, good call on the missing `ns()` and thanks for suggesting `isTruthy` which I've never used before.

Comment: I updated, think it's easier with a `reactiveValues`